# Writing Non Spatial Table into Geopackage - Python

Tags: python, gdal, fiona, geopackage

Just wondering how to write a non spatial (aspatial) table to geopackage using python. I have attempted using Fiona,

```
geopackage = 'some_geo.gpkg'    
layer = 'test_layer'
schema = {'geometry': {'type': 'aspatial'}, 'properties': [('filename', 'str')]}

with fiona.open(geopackage, 'w', layer=layer, driver='GPKG', schema=schema) as db:
    record = {'geometry': {'type': 'aspatial'},
              'properties': {'filename': filename[:-4]}}
    db.write(record)
```

This comes up with a Attribute Error because its trying to strip a dict, but I dont think thats the real issue here.

Comment: GeoPackage calls this [attributes](http://www.geopackage.org/spec/#attributes)

Answer (score 2):

Yes looks like 'aspatial' was deprecated in geopackage v1.2
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geopackage_aspatial.html

Have you tried simply not specifying the geometry field.

```
geopackage = 'some_geo.gpkg'    
layer = 'test_layer'
schema = {'properties': [('filename', 'str')]}

with fiona.open(geopackage, 'w', layer=layer, driver='GPKG', schema=schema) as db:
    record = {'properties': {'filename': filename[:-4]}}
    db.write(record)
```

Also here https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#records   under the 'writing records from scratch' section, it suggests using the output_driver = geojson    maybe in your instance you need to specify json ? geojson my force a geometry field name in the record.

Answer (score 0):

Regular SQLITE3 you can use the .dump command to copy data from one database to another.